# Commutator formula in infinite dimensions

Tags: lie-algebras, oa.operator-algebras

The commutator formula states that for A,B  elements of a Lie algebra,

$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left\{ \exp\left(-A\tfrac{t}{n}\right)\exp\left(-B\tfrac{t}{n}\right)\exp\left(A\tfrac{t}{n}\right)\exp\left(B\tfrac{t}{n}\right)\right\}^{n^2}=\exp\left(t^2[A,B]\right)$

I am interested in the case where $A=iH_1$ and $B=iH_2$ with $H_i$ self-adjoint. For finite dimensions the above certainly holds, but what happens in infinite dimensions? Under which conditions? Bounded/unbouded operators? I know that Trotter's formula has some complications in infinite dimensions, I'd be very thankful for any hints here.

Answer (score 4):

Let us start with the Campbell-Hausdorff formula for selfadjoint operators: let $H_j$ be bounded selfadjoint operators on a Hilbert space. Then
$$
e^{i\tau H_1}e^{i\tau H_2}=e^{i\tau (H_1+H_2)-\frac{\tau ^2}2[H_1,H_2]+\tau^3 R_\tau},
$$
where $
\sup_{\vert\tau\vert\le \alpha_0}\Vert R_\tau\Vert_{\mathcal B(H)}<+\infty
$
for some positive value of $\alpha_0$.
Then
$$
e^{-i\tau H_1}e^{-i\tau H_2}e^{i\tau H_1}e^{i\tau H_2}=e^{-i\tau (H_1+H_2)-\frac{\tau ^2}2[H_1,H_2]-\tau^3 R_{-\tau}}
e^{i\tau (H_1+H_2)-\frac{\tau ^2}2[H_1,H_2]+\tau^3 R_{\tau}}
$$
so that applying the formula again, you get with $S_\tau$ bounded in operator-norm near the origin
$$
e^{-i\tau H_1}e^{-i\tau H_2}e^{i\tau H_1}e^{i\tau H_2}=e^{-\tau^2[H_1,H_2]+\tau^3S_\tau}.
$$
Replacing $\tau$ by $t/n$ and waiting for $t/n$ to get smaller than $\alpha_0$, you find
the sought formula
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\bigl(
e^{-i\frac tn H_1}e^{-i\frac tn H_2}e^{i\frac tn H_1}e^{i\frac tn H_2}\bigr)^{n^2}=\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}e^{- {t^2}[H_1,H_2]+O(n^{-1})}.
$$
When the operators are unbounded, there are complications with the domains and the size of the remainders. Note also that the operator $[H_1,H_2]$ is skew-adjoint as the commutator of two selfadjoint operators so the limit is indeed unitary.

Answer (score 3):

For the unbounded case, see

Kato, Tosio [Trotter's product formula for an arbitrary pair of self-adjoint contraction semigroups.](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=538020) Topics in functional analysis (essays dedicated to M. G. Kreĭn on the occasion of his 70th birthday), pp. 185–195, Adv. in Math. Suppl. Stud., 3, Academic Press, New York-London, 1978.

The domain condition is that the square roots of $A$ and $B$ should have a dense intersection, then the convergence holds, to the exponential of the form sum of these operators.

Comment: The Trotter sum formulae are also listed in Reed-Simon Vol.1 ("Functional Analysis", Theorem VIII.31): "For all $A,B$ self-adjoint with $A+B$ essentially self-adjoint on the intersection one has $\operatorname{s-lim} (e^{itA/n}e^{itB/n})^n=e^{i(A+B)t}$; if $A,B$ additionally are bounded from below, then $\operatorname{s-lim}(e^{-tA/n}e^{-tB/n})^n=e^{-t(A+B)}$". References are listed in the notes section following the chapter.